# Crystal reports 2008 database table currencies could not be found

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm new to crystal reports and have been having an issue. The report is able to print properly on my system and on their host server however they have another server where everyone connects in through in and whenever we try to print from that server this error code pops up.

Any advice for a resolution is greatly appreciated.

Error code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The server that the report is ran on when this issue occurs - as the message suggests, it seems like the table 'currencies' which you are using in the report does not exist in the database you are using on that server.

I suggest you logon to that server where you get the error message and make sure the 'Currencies' tables exists via SSMS.